# Change height and width of image using url of the external website using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, resize, width

i have url in my image source
like this
i get this value in array for eg. img[0].so is it possible to change it with php or jquery

```
http://feedtest.tecontent.com/image.php/cover.jpg?image=/covers/cover.jpg&width=400&height=571&quality=90
```

i want change its height and width using JQuery when they load is it possible using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do some thing like this if remote site accept new width and display image as per your  needs

```
img[0] = preg_replace( array('/width=[0-9][0-9][0-9]/i', '/height=[0-9][0-9][0-9]/i'), array('width=200','height=200'), $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:** We can write a simple function to be used freequently:

```
function replaceUrlParam(url, paramName, paramValue){
    if(paramValue == null)
        paramValue = '';
    var pattern = new RegExp('\\b('+paramName+'=).*?(&|$)')
    if(url.search(pattern)>=0){
        return url.replace(pattern,'$1' + paramValue + '$2');
    }
    return url + (url.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&' : '?') + paramName + '=' + paramValue
}
```

**Step-2:** then calling the function whenever we need like below:

```
//considering the below URL:
var myUrl = 'http://feedtest.tecontent.com/image.php/cover.jpg?image=/covers/cover.jpg&width=400&height=571&quality=90';

replaceUrlParam(myUrl,'width',999999); //adjust width as per our need;
replaceUrlParam(myUrl,'height',88888); //adjust height as per our need;
```